# How do I define the default background color for window instances in a shared ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes, window, resourcedictionary

I can't seem to set a default background color for all of my windows in my application. Does anyone know how to do this?

Currently I'm setting a theme in my App.xaml file like this.

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/SomeTheme.xaml" />
```

This basically styles my entire application.

Inside of `SomeTheme.xaml` I am trying to set a default color for all of my windows like this.

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource MainColor}" x:Key="CommonBackgroundBrush" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource CommonBackgroundBrush}" />
</Style>
```

This syntax is completely ignored for derivatives of type `Window`.

Is there some way to force the style to apply to all derivatives of `Window`?

The weird thing about this syntax, is that it actually shows the correct color in the VS design preview window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your windows are not instances of `Window`, they are instances of classes derived from `Window`.  So I think you will have to list them all, but you can use `BasedOn` to help.

Comment: That's a good point... but still, there must be some way to set anything that derives from `Window`. In fact, the XAML preview shows the background being set.

Comment: That's an artifact of the way the designer works.  It **does** instantiate a `Window` so that your code-behind doesn't need to be compiled in order to do design.

Comment: Well damn. Thanks for that info... so you are saying there is no way to force all derivatives to apply the theme of their base class?

Comment: We can speculate that checking for styles of the class and all base classes was too costly, otherwise it would have been a sensible feature to add.

Comment: Thanks for your comments... they have given me quite a bit of insight

Answer (score 4):

If there really is no actual inheritance, this might be as simple as you can make it:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>         
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Dialogue}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"/>
...
```

At least you don't need to copy the whole style that way

Comment: I think this is a good alternative. It's unfortunate that I have to declare these explicitly.

Comment: Actually, I can't get this to work... are you sure this is valid?

Comment: I tried it and it worked for me, maybe something about the overall theme is different.

Comment: I'll keep tinkering... I must have something messed up

Comment: Ok, this does work... seems like there is some sort of voodoo when you use MergedDictionaries. Haven't been able to pinpoint it exactly, but things get wonky when you try to declare the Styles inside a `ResourceDictionary` that is nesting in the `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`

Answer (score 4):

Give your style a `x:Key`,

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
```

and then reference it in every window it should apply to:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" ... Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}">
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid this. I want to set styles in one place.

Comment: @Nicholas May I ask why you don't want to set a Style reference? Personally I prefer to have full control over which style applies to which control, especially after I had this ButtonStyle incident: One Monday morning I came to office and found that somebody had messed up the style of my DatePickers. It took me all morning to figure out I had it messed up myself. On the Friday before I had defined a default style for Buttons. But the DatePicker contains a Button as a PART, the style was applied to that too. I decided that keys are your friends, skip them at your own risk :-)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with keys. In fact your example is good, but I want to avoid referencing styles from each page. I really wanted an implicit style, but I guess this isn't possible. By setting it on the type (as in H.B's example), I can centrally style my pages in the same resource... which is an interesting idea for me. So no, I'm not skipping keys, in this case they just are not giving me what I want. Truth be told, Targeting the Type doesn't give me what I want either, but it looks like I will have to live with it.

Comment: If I was to think of this in relation to CSS, I would be able to set styles globally, and override them with ids and classes.. keys in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to all this so here's my 5 pence worth.
I changed the background for the grid...not sure if there are any problems doing it this way :)

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFECE9D8"/>
</Style>
```